# Display GMT + 1 time on website JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the time GMT + 1 to show on my website.

I found and bodged some code that was working fine but now it seems to be not working.

Any ideas why or do you know a better way?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}
tday=new Array("Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat");
tmonth=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
function display_ct() {
var strcount
var d1= new Date();
var x = new Date()
x.setHours(x.getHours() + 1);

var nday2=x.getDay();
var nmonth2=x.getMonth();
var ndate2=x.getDate();
var nyear2=x.getFullYear();
var nsec2=x.getSeconds();
var nhour2=x.getHours();

var nmin=d1.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9)
nmin="0"+nmin;

var x1=x.toUTCString();// changing the display to UTC string
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = ""+tday[nday2]+", "+ndate2+" "+tmonth[nmonth2]+", "+nyear2+" | "+nhour2+":"+nmin+":"+nsec2+" GMT +1";
tt=display_c();
}
</script>



<span id="ct"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = new Date();
new Date(+a - a.getTimezoneOffset() + 3600000).toISOString().split(".")[0];
```

Comment: using + before a is equivalent to a.getTime() - time in miliseconds since Jan 1 1970. with that exists a timezone, so you get rid of the zone specific time, that makes it utc and add an extra hour to it. finally the time even though the equivalent to utc time still has the zone offset after the "." if you remove it you get the required value

Comment: Thanks - Where do I add this code and how do I make it display on in the html document?

Comment: ok cool so got it to show by adding "document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = a;"

It shows fine now. How do I make it update (show the seconds moving) as it only shows the time when the page is first loaded?

It also has "(GMT Summer Time)" - any ideas on how to remove this?

Comment: `setInterval(function(){var a = new Date();
a = new Date(+a - a.getTimezoneOffset() + 3600000).toISOString().split(".")[0]; document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = a;}, 1000)`

Comment: That makes it not appear now. Tried to add it in a function and added <body onload=myFunction();> - still doesnt work

Comment: Can you write what you wrote in myfunction here?

Comment: function myFunction() {
        setInterval(function(){
        var a = new Date(); 
        a = new Date(+a - a.getTimezoneOffset() + 3600000).toISOString().split(".")[0]; 
        document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = a;
        }, 1000);
}

Comment: don't put it in a function, it will automatically start.

Comment: It wasnt so that is why I did that. It might be something else on the site that is conflicting so will look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with my code above. Seems as though it is something else on the page that is causing the issues.

```
<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id="ct"></span>
</body>

function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}
tday=new Array("Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat");
tmonth=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
function display_ct() {
var strcount
var d1= new Date();
var x = new Date()
x.setHours(x.getHours() + 1);

var nday2=x.getDay();
var nmonth2=x.getMonth();
var ndate2=x.getDate();
var nyear2=x.getFullYear();
var nsec2=x.getSeconds();
var nhour2=x.getHours();

var nmin=d1.getMinutes();
if(nmin<=9)
nmin="0"+nmin;

var x1=x.toUTCString();// changing the display to UTC string
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = ""+tday[nday2]+", "+ndate2+" "+tmonth[nmonth2]+", "+nyear2+" | "+nhour2+":"+nmin+":"+nsec2+" GMT +1";
tt=display_c();
}
```

[example js fiddle of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/peterdouglas/2x0n46s4/)